# How to log into an Amazon CodeBuild docker build container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to experiment with AWS CodeBuild. I want to run the latest docker build container and log in so I can see what's installed, and try manually installing dependencies before automating the process. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the curated image Dockerfiles from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images). You can then inspect them to see what is preinstalled, or build them yourself and experiment.

Comment: This is great news. Thanks a lot (I guess you had something to do with it @Unsigned ;-))

Answer (score 1):

CodeBuild doesn't allow you to log into a build container.  You can experiment by configuring your project's buildspec in the AWS console and run a build, before you commit the buildspec to your source code.